# How to get ISelectionService outside of UI-Thread

Tags: eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to find the currently selected Project/File and all ways I found so far are using the `ISelectionService`. The way I found to get an instance of it is:

```
 ISelectionService  selectionService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
         .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

But unfortunatly `.getActiveWorkbenchWindow()` returns null since I am not inside the UI-Thread. Is there any good way to get the ISelectionService from outside the UI-Thread?

Comment: I don't think you can get the current selection outside of the UI, because the selection exists inside the UI.  Perhaps you could get the current selection in the UI and pass the information to your non-UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Display.getDefault().synchExec(runnable);
```

to run a `Runnable` in the UI thread where you can get the selection service.

However most UI code expects to be run in the UI thread so you may need to use `syncExec` or `asyncExec` for anything that is to do with the UI.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you on how it works out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are following the wrong appraoch. You should obtain the selected project or file **before** you run the non-UI/background thread.

If your background thread is triggered by a user interaction and should operate on the selected resource (project/file) the selection may well have changed when the thread reaches the point where it queries the selection.

Instead, evaluate the selection on the UI thread and pass the extracted resource as a parameter to your background thread.

For example (simplified code):

```java
// on the UI thread:
IResource resource = ( IResource )getSelectionService().getSelection().getFirstElement();
new Thread( new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    resource.copy( ... ); /// or whatever should be done with the resource
  }
} ).start();
```

Comment: The problem is my application runs as a "subprogramm" of something that got started as an eclipse job, which means i can't really go for a clean approach :-/

Comment: I am afraid I am not entirely sure what 'subprogram' means in this context.  But if the Job that you are running in isn't passing on the necessary information for your code to run, then you should work hard to enable the job to provide these information. Calling back to the UI thread with `syncExec` or other workarounds will very likely end up in a solution that works most of the times but will bite your users in the back now and then.